# Append/Prepend em DIV com filho fixo - jQuery

Tags: jquery

Como faço para dar append/prepend em uma div que possui um filho fixo usando jQuery.

Por exemplo:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
</div>
```

Quando der o primeiro append/prepend preciso que o conteúdo seja inserido após o `.placeholder`. Os próximos devem ser relativos ao elemento já adicionado.

Por exemplo:
Append `elem um`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="elem um"></div>
</div>
```

Append `elem dois`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="elem um"></div>
    <div class="elem dois"></div>
</div>
```

Prepend `elem tres`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="elem tres"></div>
    <div class="elem um"></div>
    <div class="elem dois"></div>
</div>
```

Já tentei:

```
$('.container').find('.placeholder').after().prepend(elem_x);
$('.container').find('.placeholder').after().append(elem_x);

$('.container').find('.placeholder').next().prepend(elem_x);
$('.container').find('.placeholder').next().append(elem_x);
```

Comment: ja tentou o append sem o after?

Comment: Funciona somente para o append, no prepend a div é inserida antes do placeholder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma `div` apenas para servir de `container` para as demais e adicionar o conteúdo dentro dessa `div`. Veja um exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $divContainer = $('.container #minhaDiv');

  $divContainer.append('<div class="elem um">Um</div>');
  $divContainer.append('<div class="elem dois">Dois</div>');
  $divContainer.prepend('<div class="elem tres">Três</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="placeholder">Placeholder</div>
  <div id="minhaDiv">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não é exatamente o que eu precisava, mas vai funcionar. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer com o `:last-child` após o `.placholder`:

```js
$(".container").find(".placeholder").append("<div class='um'>Um</div>")
$(".container").find(".placeholder:last-child").append("<div class='dois'>Dois</div>")
$(".container").find(".placeholder:last-child").append("<div class='tres'>Tres</div>")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="placeholder">Placeholder</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Neste caso as divs que você está adicionando estão ficando dentro da div placeholder, elas tem que ficar fora. A resposta do @Pedro ficou mais simples. Obrigado mesmo assim! :D

Comment: É verdade, a resposta do @PedroCamaraJunior é melhor neste caso. :)